# Max value for Number type column is getting incremented when returned to UI

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, spring-mvc

I have a column in dB of Number type with precision 18 and scale 0. When I store max value (999999999999999999) it is working fine. But when I try to fetch this value the test cases show the correct value but when the output is sent to the UI it gets incremented by 1. so the value becomes 1000000000000000000.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: @ScaryWombat, I'm using plain hibernate criteria to store and fetch the value. When I debug I'm getting correct value, it only gets incremented when it is passed on to UI. I have tried this on db2 and oracle and facing same issue for both databases.

Comment: What UI framework are you using. And how does the code look?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Angular 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [double-precision floating-point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) on Wikipedia:

> The 53-bit significand precision gives from 15 to 17 significant decimal digits precision.

Your number has 18 digits of precision, so it exceeds the precision supported by a `double` and gets rounded to `1.0E18`, as can be seen by running this code:

```
double d = 999999999999999999L;
System.out.println(d);
```

Make sure the value is not assigned to a `double` anywhere in your code.

You mentioned that the correct value is seen in test code, but the UI shows it wrong, so be aware that a JavaScript Number is a double-precision floating-point value, so if you send the value to the UI as JSON, you need to send it as a String, not a Number.

Comment: Using string as angular was automatically rounding the value as you said. Thank you.